# Publish multiple points on trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory topic

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic, trajectory-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I am trying to publish multiple trajectory points of type `trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectoryPoint` on `/arm_manipulator_controller/command` topic of type `trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectoryPoint`.

When I am running the node, my robotic arm is performing only first trajectory . The other two trajectories are performed when I am pressing **ctrl+c** command. Output of `rostopic echo /arm_manipulator_command` suggesting all three trajectory points are getting published correctly.

Is it happening because of inconsistent `time_from_start` parameter of `trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectoryPoint` ?

**Output of** `rostopic echo /arm_manipulator_command` :

```
header: 
  seq: 633154
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs:         0
  frame_id: "B_Link"
joint_names: [J1, J2, J3, J4, J5, J6]
points: 
  - 
    positions: [1.5707963267948966, 1.0471975511965976, 1.5707963267948966, 3.141592653589793, -1.0471975511965976, 1.5707963267948966]
    velocities: []
    accelerations: []
    effort: []
    time_from_start: 
      secs: 1
      nsecs:         0
  - 
    positions: [-1.5707963267948966, -1.0471975511965976, -1.5707963267948966, -3.141592653589793, 1.0471975511965976, -1.5707963267948966]
    velocities: []
    accelerations: []
    effort: []
    time_from_start: 
      secs: 2
      nsecs:         0
  - 
    positions: [3.141592653589793, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0471975511965976, 0.0]
    velocities: []
    accelerations: []
    effort: []
    time_from_start: 
      secs: 3
      nsecs:         0
```

My code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory.h>
#include "ros/time.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

ros::Publisher arm_pub;
std::string joint_names[6] = { "J1", "J2", "J3", "J4", "J5", "J6" };

trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectoryPoint jointTrajectory_point(double time, int num_joints, double *joint_values){

    trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectoryPoint point;
    point.positions.resize(num_joints);
    for(int i=0; i<num_joints; i++) {
        point.positions[i] = joint_values[i];
    }
    point.time_from_start = ros::Duration(time);
    return point;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "state_publisher_node");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    arm_pub = n.advertise<trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory>("/arm_manipulator_controller/command",1);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

    int num_joints = 6;

    trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory traj;
    traj.header.frame_id = "B_Link";
    traj.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();

    traj.joint_names.resize(num_joints);
    for(int i=0;i<num_joints;i++){
        traj.joint_names[i] = joint_names[i];
    }

    traj.points.resize(3);

    double joint_values_1[6] = {M_PI/2, M_PI/3, M_PI/2, M_PI, -M_PI/3, M_PI/2}; 
    traj.points[0] = jointTrajectory_point(1.0, 6, joint_values_1);

    double joint_values_2[6] = {-M_PI/2, -M_PI/3, -M_PI/2, -M_PI, M_PI/3, -M_PI/2}; 
    traj.points[1] = jointTrajectory_point(2.0, 6, joint_values_2);

    double joint_values_3[6] = {M_PI, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, M_PI/3, 0.0}; 
    traj.points[2] = jointTrajectory_point(3.0, 6, joint_values_3);

    while(ros::ok()) {
        arm_pub.publish(traj);
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Your help would be much appreciated. I have already given a lot of time on this without any useful output.

Thanks in advance !!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362380/publish-multiple-points-on-trajectory_msgs::jointtrajectory-topic./) by [Anubhav Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/44804/anubhav-singh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2020-09-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-26**:
If you are looking to execute trajectories, why are you using the `command` topic, instead of constructing a proper `FollowJointTrajectory` action goal, creating a client and then submitting the goal using the client to the `JointTrajectory` action server?

**Comment by [Anubhav Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/44804/anubhav-singh/) on 2020-09-26**:
Thanks for replying. Yeah, that's what I am planning to try next. Above is what I was thinking of doing since a long time (in order to test robot trajectories in gazebo). So, I gave it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> When I am running the node, my robotic arm is performing only first trajectory .

(note: I'll assume *trajectory* here should actually read *trajectory point*)

This is a guess, but I believe the following may explain what you observe:

1. you are publishing messages to the `command` topic. This is a fire-and-forget interface to the `JointTrajectoryController`, meaning you get no feedback and are responsible yourself to make sure "the current trajectory" has finished executing before sending a new one
2. if you don't check for completion of a trajectory, and send a new one while the controller is executing the last trajectory you sent, the controller will try to [replace the current trajectory](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller#Trajectory_replacement) with the new one
3. you are not sending "three trajectories", but only a single one -- with three trajectory points
4. the `while`-loop in your `main(..)` causes the *same trajectory* to be published again and again at a frequency of 10 Hz

Taking all of this together, it's possible that what you see is completely according to how the `JointTrajectoryController` is specced to work:

- the same trajectory is sent as input to the controller at 10 Hz, which causes the controller to attempt execution of that trajectory
- while executing, it receives a new trajectory and will start to calculate how to *join* the two (ie: current and next trajectory)
- the replacement trajectory is the same trajectory, and has the first `time_from_start` always set to `1.0`
- as `1.0 / 10 == 0.1` < `1.0`, the first point of the trajectory will  always be the destination point

In essence, you're giving the `JointTrajectoryController` a single destination (the first point in the trajectory) and always 1 second to reach it and tell it to go again to that point at a frequency of 10 Hz.

> The other two trajectories are performed when I am pressing `ctrl+c` command

(again: I'll assume *trajectory* should actually read *trajectory point*)

This can be explained by the fact that once you stop your script, the `JointTrajectoryController` finally gets a chance to completely execute the trajectory (ie: without any replacement trajectories coming in), so it will (should) reach points 2 and 3 in 2 and 3 seconds respectively.

Finally: as I wrote in my initial comment: it's ok to use the `command` interface/topic, but you'll have to make sure the controller has executed the trajectory before sending a new one (or actually make use of the *replacement* capabilities of course).

If you're not interested in replacement, I would suggest you instead use the [action interface](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller#Sending_trajectories) which lets you wait on completion of a goal, notifying you when it's ok to send a new trajectory.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anubhav Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/44804/anubhav-singh/) on 2020-09-29**:
Thank you so much for your answer. I will try these points.

**Comment by [Contour](https://answers.ros.org/users/89486/contour/) on 2021-12-09**:
I met the same problem. Using action interface actually solved it. Thanks a lot !